# Is there a word that means "follow musically"?

Tags: word-request

Think of a pianist who is accompanying a violonist. What would you call the act of playing music and adjusting your tune, melody and playing to the musician you are accompanying. So the word accompanying is used a lot, but it's not specific enough. Accompaniment means a vocal or instrumental part that supports another, often solo, part, but it doesn't tell you that it's done particularly well and with respect to the tune, melody, playing.

For example:

> Her piano ___ the playing of the violonist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such a term - an **accompanist** is someone who **accompanies** a soloist, but there's no specific word for a very good accompanist.  Instead, you'd have to add an adjective or an adverb, as appropriate.  Some examples, beginning with your fill-in-the-blank:

> Her piano **accompaniment perfectly underscored** the playing of the violinist.
>
> She is a **skilled accompanist** who is often hired by the very best violinists.
>
> She **brilliantly accompanied** the virtuoso as he improvised a new cadenza.

It is understood that the job of an accompanist is to follow and support the soloist, so if you use words like **brilliant, skilled, or perfect**, to modify **accompany** or any of its derivative forms, then it is understood that they are doing a brilliant, skilled, or perfect job at following and supporting the soloist.

Answer (score 1):

Correction - the word is spelled *violinist*, not *violonist*.

I am not sure there is a specific word in English for what you're seeking. I can think of some generic ways of describing such musical accompaniment:

> Her piano playing *complemented* the violinist's playing.
>
> The pianist accompanied the violinist *sensitively*.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for *répétiteur*

> Accompanying and coaching opera singers throughout the rehearsal process, 
>   the repetiteur is a skilled pianist, conductor, and vocal teacher rolled 
>   into one.
>
> these pianists serve as accompanists, skillfully reducing the complicated 
>   orchestral scores for piano in a way that preserves the spirit of a live orchestra.

https://www.berklee.edu/careers/roles/repetiteur

The term appears to imply a specialism in opera, but might be used for similar roles in other musical genres.